# How do I open a list and select an option in Selenium WebDriver when Select and WebElement do not work

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm new to Java and Selenium WebDriver. To learn how to use WebDriver, I decided to automate the flight booking process on the Emirates website. I've had problems but now I'm truly stuck. When I'm entering in my flight details, prior to selecting a flight, and I decide on leg two, of an advanced journey, to travel "First Class", I cannot figure out how to automate this process - the same applies to increasing the number of adult passengers. I haven't included the html here but it can be found when inspecting the elements in the lists.

So the code that works is this:

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

   // This opens the browser on the Emirates homepage
    driver.get("http://www.emirates.com/uk/english/");

    // Opening main menu item "Book"
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='book']/a/span")).click();

    // For the second leg of the flight, I wish to travel first class >
    // therefore I open the drop down and select "First 
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen")).click();
```

However, I cannot work out how to select "First Class" and have this appear as the class I would like to travel as, and proceed with the booking. Can anyone help?

This is taken from FirePath (Xpath displayed):

```
<li id="option_id_ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen_2" class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2" text="First Class" role="option" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">
```

When I right click on First Class from the combo box

And the html from the div:

```
<div id="ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen" title="Select your preferred cabin class for your inbound flight. - Selected: First Class" style="width: 100%;" class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch"><a aria-expanded="false" title="Select your preferred cabin class for your inbound flight. - Selected: First Class" class="chosen-single" role="combobox" tabindex="0"><em aria-live="polite" class="visually-hidden">Selected: First Class</em><span class="cabin-class_3" aria-hidden="true">First Class</span><div><strong></strong></div></a><div class="chosen-drop" aria-hidden="true"><div class="chosen-search" aria-hidden="true"><label class="label-hidden" for="chosenLabel1">Label</label><input aria-activedescendant="option_id_ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen_0" readonly="" id="chosenLabel1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Input a value to search" style="display: none;" type="text"></div><ul class="chosen-results" tabindex="-1"><li tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" role="option" text="Economy Class" id="option_id_ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen_0" data-option-array-index="0" style="" class="active-result"><span style="display: inline;float:none;">Economy Class</span></li><li aria-selected="false" role="option" text="Business Class" id="option_id_ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen_1" data-option-array-index="1" style="" class="active-result"><span style="display: inline;float:none;">Business Class</span></li><li tabindex="-1" aria-selected="true" role="option" text="First Class" id="option_id_ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen_2" data-option-array-index="2" style="" class="active-result result-selected"><span style="display: inline;float:none;">First Class</span></li></ul></div></div>
<a aria-expanded="false" title="Select your preferred cabin class for your inbound flight. - Selected: First Class" class="chosen-single" role="combobox" tabindex="0"><em aria-live="polite" class="visually-hidden">Selected: First Class</em><span class="cabin-class_3" aria-hidden="true">First Class</span><div><strong></strong></div></a>
<em aria-live="polite" class="visually-hidden">Selected: First Class</em>
<span class="cabin-class_3" aria-hidden="true">First Class</span>
```

[The image shows the output from Firepath after clicking on First Class, in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnv4Q.png)

Comment: can you please provide a snippet of the html you want to select?

Comment: posting html(dom) will help

Comment: Hi Abaddon666, I've included the XPath for what I think is the right area of the code

Comment: Thanks Anil Chandra, have added the html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Opening main menu item "Book"
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@id='book']/a/span")));
 element.click();

// For the second leg of the flight, I wish to travel first class >
// therefore I open the drop down and select "First 


 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li#ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen")));
 ele.click();
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I keep getting a vector smash exception in Eclipse's console: 
`Vector smash protection is enabled.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: li#ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"li#ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen"}
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)`

Comment: so the problem here is with this element  selector `li#ctl00_c_CtWNW_flightClass1_chosen` try replacing it with `li[text='First Class']`

Comment: thanks for your help but that doesn't seem to work either